# Find the line with maximum occurrence

Tags: regex, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I use sublime text so if what I'm looking for is not native in SB, I need a regex to find in a document the line who contains the maximum occurences of something.

For example, if my document contain:

```
(line 1)    blabla;;bla;bla
(line 2)    blabla;;;bla;;bla
(line 3)    blabla;bla;;;bla
```

And I search the line that contains the maximum of ";"
The result of the regex in SB should be the line 2.

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the time to write a plugin that does what you want. This is how:

Create a folder `LineMaxOcc` in your `Packages` directory. Within, create two files:

File `LineMaxOcc.py`:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin


class PromptLineMaxOccCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):

    def run(self):
        self.window.show_input_panel("Search for:", "", self.on_done, None, None)
        pass

    def on_done(self, text):
        self.window.active_view().run_command("line_max_occ", {"text": text} )


class LineMaxOccCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):

    def run(self, edit, text):

        buf = self.view.substr(sublime.Region(0, self.view.size()))

        result = 0
        currentMax = 0

        i = 0
        for line in buf.split("\n"):
            count = line.count(text) 
            if count > currentMax:
                currentMax = count
                result = i
            i += 1

        pt = self.view.text_point(result, 0)

        self.view.sel().clear()
        self.view.sel().add(sublime.Region(pt))

        self.view.show(pt)
```

and file `Default.sublime-keymap`:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+g"], "command": "prompt_line_max_occ" }
]
```

This should work immediately.

Cheers!